# Importing Complex Modules into Processing.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, export, processing

I'm currently using PyGame to build games on python, however exporting becomes rather difficult as Py2Exe and Py2App are almost the only ways to do so and are not very effective. I tried to using the wonderful exporting mechanic in Processing (in Python mode), but this opened a Pandora's box of problems.

1. How do you import modules in Processing.py ? I read that if the module is in the form of a PY file it is simply to be located in the same folder as the sketch. But some modules, like PyGame, are more complex and require an installer or a wheel (WHL file, which is installed through PIP).
2. During some testing, I tried to export a simple one-line program ( print('a') ) but the 'application.windows64' folder was missing an EXE file. I'm not an expert, but I think that might be a problem :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

processing.py is not compatible with CPython (native python), nor with any c-language modules.